# Jquery passdata PHP data to variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the  following php function :

```
public function get_dataset() {
  $dataset = "[";
  $data_set = $this->operations_model->get_date();
  foreach ($data_set as $value) {
    $date = $value['date'];
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $dataset .= '[' . $date . ',' . $value['revenue'] . '],';
  }
  $dataset = substr($dataset, 0, -1);
  $dataset .= "]";

  echo $dataset;
}
```

Which returns a dataset from a database query, the data returned is in the  following format :

```
[[1433163200,15000],[1433163200,5800],[1433163200,5800],[1433163200,5800],[1435150400,15000],[1433163200,5800],[1433163200,5800],[1433336000,5800],[1433163200,5800],[1433163200,15000],[1435755200,5800],[1435755200,5800],[1435755200,5800],[1435755200,5800],[1435755200,5800],[1441976000,15000],[1441976000,5800],[1441976000,5800],[1441976000,5800],[1435755200,5800],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,15000],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,15000],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,5800],[1438433600,15000],[1441112000,5800],[1441112000,5800],[1441112000,5800],[1441112000,15000],[1441112000,5800],[1443704000,5800],[1443704000,5800],[1443704000,5800],[1443704000,15000],[1443704000,5800],[1444742133,5800],[1444742133,5800],[1444742133,5800],[1444742133,5800],[1444742510,15000],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742510,5800],[1444742518,15000],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742518,5800],[1444742671,15000],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444742671,5800],[1444743338,5800],[1444743338,15000],[1444743489,5800],[1444743489,15000],[1444743551,5800],[1444743551,15000],[1444743639,5800],[1444743639,15000],[1444743749,5800],[1444743749,15000],[1444743810,5800],[1444743810,15000],[1444743900,15000],[1444743920,15000],[1444743949,15000],[1444744037,15000],[1444744104,5800],[1445251070,5800],[1445251070,15000],[1445251080,5800],[1445251080,15000],[1445251085,5800],[1445251085,15000]]
```

I would like to pass this data to a jquery variable so that is comes back in the  following syntax :

```
var data = [
  [1325365200000, 17],
  [1325451600000, 74],
  [1325538000000, 6],
  [1325624400000, 39],
  [1325710800000, 20],
  [1325797200000, 85],
  [1325883600000, 7]
];
```

In a jquery variable. I have tried the  following :

```
var revenue = ["<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/get_dataset"];
```

But it's not working, please advise on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can either pass the variable on load of the view/ Use AJAX instead to load the data after page load/dynamically.

Comment: run `get_dataset()` directly from browser and check what data you are getting there??

Comment: And when are you call ing this function??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju when I run it through the browser , I get the data as posted in the question, when I do a console.log  console.log(revenue); I get the following :  ["http://localhost:8888/un.../operations/get_dataset"]

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju when I run it through the browser , I get the data as posted in the question, when I do a console.log  console.log(revenue); I get the following :  ["http://localhost:8888/un.../operations/get_dataset"]

Comment: you r giving url as value to variable, u shud execute that and assign the vakue.

Comment: @user689017 check the answer. That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make `revenue` as global variable, on load of the pagr, call ajax and assign the value to variable, then user it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/get_dataset",
        dataType:"HTML",
        success: function(data) {
            revenue = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can even use file_get_contents() if you don't want to use ajax.